# excel VBA - return Criteria1 Array from an Autofilter

Tags: excel, vba, filter, autofilter

I have a table that I need to return all of the toggled values. When i record a macro after selecting which ones i want it looks like this

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$P$1000").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=Array("A" _
    , "B", "C", "D", "E", "G"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

the problem i have is that the a,b,c, etc values that will be filtered by the user will always be changing so I can't hardcode any criteria that way.

is there a way i can return an array of what is toggled on in a fashion similar to how this looks?

```
msgbox ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$P$1000").criteria1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Beginning with data like:

[image]

this sub applies a filter:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Range("A1:C22").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$C$22").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Array( _
        "Alice", "Boris", "Mike"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

[image]

and this sub will:

- identify which columns are filtered
- of the filtered columns, which have selections made
- list the actual selections

```
Sub FilterInformation()
    Dim st As String, ws As Worksheet, rg As Range, boo As Boolean

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    On Error GoTo GetMeOut
    Set rg = ws.AutoFilter.Range

    MsgBox "Filter range" & vbCrLf & rg.Address

    N = ws.AutoFilter.Filters.Count
    MsgBox "Number of filters" & vbCrLf & N

    For i = 1 To N
        boo = ws.AutoFilter.Filters.Item(i).On
        MsgBox i & "==>" & boo
        If boo Then
            MsgBox UBound(ws.AutoFilter.Filters.Item(i).Criteria1) & " items in array"
            U = UBound(ws.AutoFilter.Filters.Item(i).Criteria1)
            L = LBound(ws.AutoFilter.Filters.Item(i).Criteria1)
            For j = L To U
                MsgBox ws.AutoFilter.Filters.Item(i).Criteria1(j)
            Next
        End If

    Next
    Exit Sub
GetMeOut:
    MsgBox ("no filters in sheet")
End Sub
```